# Tensorflow : How to use ResidualWrapper and HighwayWrapper in tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

I am trying to use ResidualWrapper and HighwayWrapper in my network structure but I am getting shape mismatch error.

So What I have tried :

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.contrib import rnn

tf.reset_default_graph()

a = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,[2,5,10])




with tf.variable_scope('encoder') as scope:

    model = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(tf.nn.rnn_cell.ResidualWrapper (rnn.DropoutWrapper(tf.nn.rnn_cell.GRUCell(4),dtype=tf.float32)),inputs=a,dtype=tf.float32)



with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    rnn_outputs, final_state = sess.run(model,feed_dict={a:np.random.randint(0,10,[2,5,10])})

    print(rnn_outputs.shape)
    print(final_state.shape)
```

But I am getting error:

```
ValueError: Shapes (2, 10) and (2, 4) are incompatible
```

How to properly use ResidualWrapper and HighwayWrapper in Tensorflow?

Should I give same no_of_units for GRUcell as input dim?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are actually a problem. Let me take `ResidualWrapper` as an example. Residual network connects input in front of layer directly to output layer behind layer. As shown in the following figure:

[image]

This means that the `ResidualWrapper` adds the inputs to the outputs of the `GRUCell` it wraps. So you have to make sure that the last dimension of the input and output of the `GRUCell` it wraps must be the same. In your case, the last dimension of your output shape is `4` and the last dimension of your input shape is `10`. The two can't be added together, so this error occurs.

You need to add a layer before the residual layer to make its last dimension is `4`.

```
with tf.variable_scope('encoder') as scope:
    model = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(
        rnn.MultiRNNCell([
            rnn.DropoutWrapper(tf.nn.rnn_cell.GRUCell(4), dtype=tf.float32)
            ,tf.nn.rnn_cell.ResidualWrapper(
                rnn.DropoutWrapper(tf.nn.rnn_cell.GRUCell(4), dtype=tf.float32)
            )
        ])
        , inputs=a,
        dtype=tf.float32)
```

Or change the residual layer unit number to `10`.

```
with tf.variable_scope('encoder') as scope:
    model = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(
        tf.nn.rnn_cell.ResidualWrapper(rnn.DropoutWrapper(tf.nn.rnn_cell.GRUCell(10), dtype=tf.float32)), inputs=a,
        dtype=tf.float32)
```